# Different Job , Sched Chain, Sched Job, Sched Windows, and Sched Job classes in Toad For Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, toad

Hy ..
sorry before i need ask

I can not find literature on `Different Toad Job , Sched Chain, Sched Windows, Sched Job and Sched Job classes  description` in Toad for Oracle.
 Is there any explanation about it?

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i58E6.jpg)

Comment: What are these? Could you post a screenshot so that we could see it?

Comment: Have a look at [Oracle Scheduler Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/schedover.htm#ADMIN033)

Comment: Thank you, @Wernfried. I was puzzled with a *different TOAD job* (TOAD job? What's that?).

Comment: @Littlefoot, Oracle provides **Scheduler Jobs** and old style **Jobs**, see [DBMS_JOB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_job.htm#ARPLS019)

Comment: Yes, I know that, @Wernfried. It is the "TOAD job" I don't know. Never mind, it seems you got it right and helped me understand what's going on. Thanks again.

Comment: Toad its Tools development Oracle ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation [Oracle Scheduler Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/schedover.htm#ADMIN033)

> - **Chains** are the means by which you can implement dependency scheduling, in which job starts depend on the outcomes of one or more
>     previous jobs.
> - **Credentials** are user name and password pairs stored in a dedicated database object. Scheduler jobs use credentials to
>     authenticate themselves with a database instance or the operating
>     system in order to run.
> - **Job classes** enable you to assign the same attributes to member jobs, set resource allocation for member jobs, and group jobs for
>     prioritization.
> - You use **jobs** and other scheduler objects for task scheduling.
> - A **program** object (program) describes what is to be run by the Scheduler.
> - A **schedule** object (schedule) specifies when and how many times a job is run. Schedules can be shared by multiple jobs. For example, the
>     end of a business quarter may be a common time frame for many jobs.
>     Rather than defining an end-of-quarter schedule each time a new job is
>     defined, job creators can point to a named schedule.
> - A **window** is an interval of time to run a job. You create windows to automatically start jobs or to change resource allocation among
>     jobs during various time periods of the day, week, and so on. A window
>     is represented by an interval of time with a well-defined beginning
>     and end, such as "from 12am-6am".
> - A **group** designates a list of Scheduler objects. Instead of passing a list of objects as an argument to a DBMS_SCHEDULER package
>     procedure, you create a group that has those objects as its members,
>     and then pass the group name to the procedure.

Most important is of course the SCHEDULER JOB. Personally I am using JOB and SCHEDULE. All other objects I never used so far.